# Kendo Grid - Pagination for only visible rows (Exclude Hidden rows)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

As I am trying Kendo Grid for the first time. I have few rows in front end where they are in Hidden mode. but in Pagination even Hidden rows are getting counted.
Can we exclude hidden rows. or just do pagination for visible rows.

Could not find better results on this.

```
   $('#grid').html('');
    var grid = $j("#grid").kendoGrid({        
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns: [
                {
                    field: "Active",
                    template: '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ></input>',
                    headerTemplate: '<a class="k-link" href="#"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" class="k-link"/></a>',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: false
                },
                { field: "Id", title: "Id", width: 90 },
                { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 125 },
                { field: "Program", title: "Program", width: 125 },
                { field: "Date", title: "Month", type: "date", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'dd MMM yyyy') #", width: 125 },
               ,attributes: { "class": "# if(Language === 'English') { # # } else {#rowhide#} #" }}],
        pageable: {
            change: function (e) {
                var gridData = $j("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data;
                var selectedRowCount = 0;
                $.each(gridData, function (index, currentData) {
                    var checkBoxRow = $("tr[data-uid='" + currentData.uid + "']");
                    var checkBox = checkBoxRow.find('.checkbox');
                    var isPresent = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                        if (selectedRows[i] == currentData.StatementsHistoryId ) {
                            isPresent = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isPresent) {
                        checkBox[0].checked = true;
                        selectedRowCount += 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        checkBox[0].checked = false;
                    }
                });
                if (selectedRowCount != 0 && gridData && gridData.length == selectedRowCount)
                    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
                else
                    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
            }
        },
        editable: true,
        sortable: true

    }).data("kendoGrid").table.on("change", ".checkbox", selectRecord);
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is based on datasource and you are hidding them using CSS.
You should move your hide condition in dataBound event and remove them from datasource.